# Uploading Image from Phone to RecyclerView GridView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm trying to use glide to do this. I have a Gridview recycler view with 9 pictures already in the Recycler. There is an OnClickListener implemented which takes me to the phone's gallery so I can upload an image into the Recycler view. Problem arises when I use mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(imagePosition). Glide needs an imageView, but the layoutmanager returns a CardView? from the custom XML for each item in the Recycler View. Exactly, how would I go about doing this? Thank you!!

Error:

```
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.gralloc.disable_ahardware_buffer"
W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.imagegridactivity, PID: 25530
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { {com.example.imagegridactivity/com.example.imagegridactivity.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.cardview.widget.CardView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4845)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.cardview.widget.CardView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
        at com.example.imagegridactivity.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:128)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4838)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25530 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

Adapter:

```
public class AnimalsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AnimalsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ImageView imageView;

    private Uri imageUri;
    private ArrayList<animal_item> mDataSet;
    private Context mContext;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public ArrayList<animal_item> getDataSet() {
        return mDataSet;
    }

    public void setDataSet(ArrayList<animal_item> mDataSet) {
        this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
    }

    public ImageView getImageView() {
        return imageView;
    }

    public void setImageView(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    public void setContext(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public Uri getImageUri() {
        return imageUri;
    }

    public void setImageUri(Uri imageUri) {
        this.imageUri = imageUri;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClick(int position);

    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {

        mListener = listener;

    }

    public AnimalsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<animal_item> DataSet) {
        mDataSet = DataSet;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public ArrayList<animal_item> DataSet() {

        return mDataSet;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View v, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(v);

            mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);

            mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (listener != null) {

                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) ;
                        listener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            });
            mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll);
        }



        public ImageView getImageView() {

            return mImageView;
        }

        public void setImageView(ImageView mImageView) {

            this.mImageView = mImageView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public AnimalsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Create a new View
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v, (OnItemClickListener) mListener);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final animal_item animalItem = mDataSet.get(position);

        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(animalItem.getImageResource());

        imageView = holder.mImageView;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mDataSet.size();
    }

}
```

Individual View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="4dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="3dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context mContext;

    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private AnimalsAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private ArrayList<animal_item> arrayList;
    private Uri imageUri;

    private int imagePosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mContext = getApplicationContext();


        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF677589"))
        );

        mRelativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.rl);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        final int[] imageArray = new int[9];

        for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {

            imageArray[i] = R.mipmap.pic1_foreground;

        }

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {

            int image = imageArray[i];
            arrayList.add(new animal_item(image));

        }

        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 3);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new AnimalsAdapter(mContext, arrayList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new AnimalsAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            }
        });

        ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT, 0) {

            final ArrayList aL = new ArrayList<>();

            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder dragged, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {

                int position_dragged = dragged.getAdapterPosition();
                int position_target = target.getAdapterPosition();

                Collections.swap(arrayList, position_dragged, position_target);
                mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(position_dragged, position_target);
                //Collections.copy(mQuestion11List, aL);

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

            }
        });

        helper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        imageUri = data.getData();

        //mAdapter.getDataSet().get(imagePosition).setImageResource();
        Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(imageUri).into(mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(imagePosition));

    }
}
```

Individual Item:

```
package com.example.imagegridactivity;

public class animal_item {

    private int imageResource;

    public animal_item(int imageResource) {
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
    }

    public int getImageResource() {
        return imageResource;
    }

    public void setImageResource(int imageResource) {
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
    }
}
```

Comment: The method mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(imagePosition) return the view representing the corresponding adapter position. You have to use findViewById(R.id.tv) on that returned view to get the image view and pass it to glide as target.

Comment: @Antonio Thank you Antonio. This worked! Specifically, I got the image position in question from the onClickListener and put it into: Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(imageUri).into((ImageView) mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(imagePosition).findViewById(R.id.tv)); Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(imagePosition) return the view representing the corresponding adapter position. You have to use findViewById(R.id.tv) on that returned view to get the image view and pass it to glide as target.